# Move the Highstock navigator position

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to move the Highstock chart navigator from the bottom of the chart to the top?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, please take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/jBUGN/

```
 navigator: {
        top:40,

    },
```

Comment: This has some bad side-effects. When you drag the handles in the navigator the scroller will start panning and highstock will get confused about where to show tooltips, handle hover/click events etc.

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded answer from Sebastian: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/jBUGN/18/ Instead of setting top for xAxis and yAxis, set marginTop: value:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        marginTop: 140
    },

    navigator: {
        top:40,

    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```