# Dynamically move highstock navigator

Tags: highcharts

I'm having some trouble with highstock. I've figured out how to shuffle around other series via the y axis object, however I'm looking to dynamically add more series, and shift the navigator down after I add additional series, along with increasing the height of the containing div as more series are added.

My current approach to moving the navigator is to update the top property of the y axis assigned to the navigator, as informed by this answer:
[Move the Highstock navigator position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399490/move-the-highstock-navigator-position)

```
function moveNavigator(){
chart.navigator.yAxis.update({
        height : 50,
        top: 202
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwhcj3e7/2/

If my understanding were correct this fiddle should move the navigator from on top of the chart to the bottom of the chart. Is there a way to accomplish this behavior without completely making a new chart object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chart.update()` method (available from version 5) and update navigator's top property.

```
 chart.update({
        navigator: {
          top: 202,
          height: 50
      }
    });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dwhcj3e7/3/